# Pass the key on onClick event - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, react-hooks

I pass the key of my Hook that I map, like this :

```
Object.entries(userWalletIncomes).map(([key, value]) => {
                        return (
                            <div id="incomeTable" className="text-left mx-auto flex" key={key}>
                                <p className="w-32 border p-1 capitalize">{key} :</p>
                                <p className="w-32 border p-1 text-green-500">{value}€</p>
                                <button onClick={(key) => handleDeleteIncome(key)}><i className="fas fa-times text-red-400 border p-1"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
```

And `on click` on the button, I give the `key` in the call of the function.

When I log it, instead of giving the simple string, it gives me this :

```
SyntheticBaseEvent {_reactName: "onClick", _targetInst: null, type: "click", nativeEvent: MouseEvent, target: i.fas.fa-times.text-red-400.border.p-1, …}
```

Inside of this object, there isn't my key. I don't understand why. Where is my mistake ?

Thanks for helping me understand

Comment: Just remove (key) from the parameters, then you are good to go ;) 
I.e leave it like onClick={()=>handleDeleteIncome(key)).
What you are doing is that you are passing the event of your click (naming it as key) instead of actually passing the variable you want.

Comment: @ViktorSandberg Ok I understand better my mistake. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button onClick={(event) => handleDeleteIncome(key)}>
  <i className="fas fa-times text-red-400 border p-1"></i>
</button>
```

You are simply redeclaring the "key" variable in the onClick event.

Comment: Omg... Sometime the answer is so logical we don't even see it. Thank you very much. 